# Elements draggable amongst multiple containers/grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to be able to drag/sort elements among multiple grids. Pretty much like on the following snippet/image.

However, problem is, that when i am dragging element outside of the grid, it will begin to jump/hide unexpectedly and act messy. Is there any better way (can also be some plugin), that can help me achieve this behaviour?

Thank you very much.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".sortable-grid").sortable({
    revert: true
});

$(".sortable-element").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable-grid",
    revert: "invalid"
});
});
```

```css
.sortable-grid {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.sortable-element {
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="sortable-grid">
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
          <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
            <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
          <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r0Op.png)

Comment: I am pretty much lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need the Draggable. Since all the items are under the Sortable, they can already be dragged.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sortable-grid").sortable({
    revert: true
  });
});
```

```css
.sortable-grid {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.sortable-element {
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="sortable-grid">
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
        <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
        <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sortable-grid">
        <div class="sortable-element">Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```